# Determining which version of VB a program was compiled with

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, decompiling

How do you determine which version of visual basic a program (.ocx, .exe, or .dll) was compiled with?

(I'm referring to visual basic 6 and before, not .net).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can often tell what version was used to compile an old VB program based on the dependencies for the program.

**MSVBVM60.dll** for VB6 compiled programs

**MSVBVM50.dll** for VB5

**VB40032.dll** for VB4 32bit

**VB40016.dll** for VB4 16bit.

Comment: So I guess the best way is to read the import table and see if the .dlls match.